# "Deferred inline method `foo` in trait `Foo` cannot be invoked": Pairs

Tags: scala, inline, implicit, scala-3, given

I was just experimenting with the behavior of `given`s and `inline` in Scala 3.2.2, and ran into the following example:

```
trait Max[X]:
  inline def max(a: X, b: X): X
  
inline given maxForDoubles: Max[Double] with
  inline def max(a: Double, b: Double) = if a < b then b else a

inline given maxForPairs[A, B](using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B]): Max[(A, B)] with
  inline def max(x: (A, B), y: (A, B)) =
    (mA.max(x._1, y._1), mB.max(x._2, y._2))

@main def entryPoint(): Unit = {
  println(summon[Max[(Double, Double)]].max((10.0, 3.0), (20.0, -7.0)))
}
```

Instead of just printing the pair `(20, 3)`, it fails the compilation with the following error:

```
12 |  println(summon[Max[(Double, Double)]].max((10.0, 3.0), (20.0, -7.0)))
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |          Deferred inline method max in trait Max cannot be invoked
   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |Inline stack trace
   |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
   |This location contains code that was inlined from buggy-example.scala:9
 9 |    (mA.max(x._1, y._1), mB.max(x._2, y._2))
   |     ^^^^^^
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems that it should know everything statically. Any clues why it's failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tried to use [alias givens](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/givens.html#alias-givens) rather than [given instances](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/givens.html#given-instances) (`with`-syntax)

```
inline given maxForDoubles: Max[Double] = new Max[Double]:
  inline override def max(a: Double, b: Double): Double = if a < b then b else a

inline given maxForPairs[A, B](using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B]): Max[(A, B)] = new Max[(A, B)]:
  inline override def max(x: (A, B), y: (A, B)): (A, B) = (mA.max(x._1, y._1), mB.max(x._2, y._2))
```

this wouldn't work because of

```
Implementation restriction: nested inline methods are not supported
```

But with `with`-syntax nested `inline` are allowed because

```
inline given maxForDoubles: Max[Double] with
  inline override def max(a: Double, b: Double): Double = if a < b then b else a

inline given maxForPairs[A, B](using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B]): Max[(A, B)] with
  inline override def max(x: (A, B), y: (A, B)): (A, B) = (mA.max(x._1, y._1), mB.max(x._2, y._2))
```

is actually

```
class maxForDoubles extends Max[Double]:
  inline override def max(a: Double, b: Double): Double = if a < b then b else a

inline given maxForDoubles: maxForDoubles = new maxForDoubles

class maxForPairs[A, B](using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B]) extends Max[(A, B)]:
  inline override def max(x: (A, B), y: (A, B)): (A, B) = (mA.max(x._1, y._1), mB.max(x._2, y._2))

inline given maxForPairs[A, B](using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B]): maxForPairs[A, B] = new maxForPairs[A, B]
```

Indeed, with `-Xprint:pickleQuotes` option (or `-Xprint:typer`) the `with`-syntax produces

```
//    given class maxForDoubles() extends Object(), App.Max[Double] {
//      override inline def max(a: Double, b: Double): Double = 
//        (if a.<(b) then b else a):Double
//    }
//    final inline given def maxForDoubles: App.maxForDoubles = 
//      new App.maxForDoubles():App.maxForDoubles
//    given class maxForPairs[A >: Nothing <: Any, B >: Nothing <: Any](using 
//      mA: App.Max[A]
//    , mB: App.Max[B]) extends Object(), App.Max[
//      Tuple2[maxForPairs.this.A, maxForPairs.this.B]
//    ] {
//      A
//      B
//      protected given val mA: App.Max[A]
//      protected given val mB: App.Max[B]
//      override inline def max(x: Tuple2[maxForPairs.this.A, maxForPairs.this.B]
//        , 
//      y: Tuple2[maxForPairs.this.A, maxForPairs.this.B]): (A, B) = 
//        Tuple2.apply[A, B](this.App$maxForPairs$$inline$mA.max(x._1, y._1), 
//          this.App$maxForPairs$$inline$mB.max(x._2, y._2)
//        ):(A, B)
//      def App$maxForPairs$$inline$mA: App.Max[A] = maxForPairs.this.mA
//      def App$maxForPairs$$inline$mB: App.Max[B] = maxForPairs.this.mB
//    }
//    final inline given def maxForPairs[A >: Nothing <: Any, B >: Nothing <: Any]
//      (
//    using mA: App.Max[A], mB: App.Max[B]): App.maxForPairs[A, B] = 
//      new App.maxForPairs[A, B](using mA, mB)():App.maxForPairs[A, B]
```

Let's temporarily simplify the `with`-syntax removing `using` and `maxForDoubles`

```
class maxForPairs[A, B]/*(using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B])*/ extends Max[(A, B)]:
  inline override def max(x: (A, B), y: (A, B)): (A, B) = ??? // (mA.max(x._1, y._1), mB.max(x._2, y._2))

// inline given maxForPairs[A, B]/*(using mA: Max[A], mB: Max[B])*/: maxForPairs[A, B] = new maxForPairs[A, B]
```

Then the difference between

```
val inst: maxForPairs[Double, Double] = new maxForPairs[Double, Double]
inst.max((10.0, 3.0), (20.0, -7.0)) // compiles
```

and

```
val inst: Max[(Double, Double)] = new maxForPairs[Double, Double]
inst.max((10.0, 3.0), (20.0, -7.0)) // doesn't compile: Deferred inline method max in trait Max cannot be invoked
```

is understandable because there is a rule

> 3. Inline methods can also be abstract. An abstract inline method can be implemented only by other inline methods. It cannot be invoked directly:
>
>    ```
>    abstract class A:
>      inline def f: Int
>
>    object B extends A:
>      inline def f: Int = 22
>
>    B.f         // OK
>    val a: A = B
>    a.f         // error: cannot inline f in A.
>    ```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html#rules-for-overriding

And `max` is exactly an abstract inline method in the trait `Max`.

`summon[Max[(Double, Double)]]` returns the precise type of implicit:  `maxForPairs[Double, Double] <: Max[(Double, Double)]` (as `shapeless.the` in Scala 2), not just `Max[(Double, Double)]` (as `implicitly` in Scala 2).

But if we restore `using` and `maxForDoubles` then for some reason this confuses inlines: both options for `val inst` (`: maxForPairs[Double, Double]` and `: Max[(Double, Double)]`) produce `Deferred inline method max in trait Max cannot be invoked`.

This seems to be a bug or underspecified feature. Try to open a ticket at https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues

By the way, sometimes `with`-syntax behaves weirdly in comparison with alias givens (even without inlines):
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/8882